# What does go wrong in Cellular homology if one considers projective limits of celullar complexes instead of CW-complexes?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, cw-complexes

Consider a nice topological space $X$ (e.g. the 3-sphere) and consider inside a decreasing sequence of compact subsets $(K_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$  such that $K_\infty:=\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N} K_n$ is 0-dimensional. Assume further more that you have a filtration of CW-complexes $(\mathcal S_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$, each on $X\setminus Int(K_n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. Now consider the projective limit of the system
$$ X/K_{n+1} \xrightarrow{\pi_{n+1,n}} X/K_n$$
where $X/K_n := K/\sim$  with $x\sim y$ identifying elements of the same connected components of $K_n$.  We can thus define $X':=\varprojlim X/K_n$ which comes with a natural map $X\rightarrow X'$. Assuming $X$ and the $K_n$ are nice enough (like $X$ compact and for any neighborhood  $\mathcal U$ of any given $x\in K_\infty$ there exists an $n$ big enough so that the connected component of $x$ in $K_n$ is a subset of $\mathcal U$), the map $X\rightarrow X'$ is an homeomorphism.

Now, one could try to define a " pro-cellular" homology for such a  projective limit of CW-complexes : $X^{(0)}$ would be the 0-dimensional subset of $X$ given by all the vertices of the CW-complexes plus $K_{\infty}$, then $X^{(1)}$ is given by all the edges of the CW-complexes,...

This cellular decomposition fails to be a CW-complex in several ways but the relative homology defining the cellular chain complex $H(X^{(n)},X^{n-1};G)$  is still composed of free $G$-modules and is what one would expect for a CW-complex i.e. the free module generated by the $n$-facets.

Does one still have equivalence with singular homology?, I guess the answer is *No* but I don't see why.